# json parse data set search condition is no working

Tags: android

I parse json data successfully , i can show it on my recyclerView.

it's my data source:
(had solved the issue)
I want to set a search condition about `month > 5`

I had set a `String.equal("compareString");` before, it worked.

But when i set the month in this case, it's not working.

do i set something wrong? any help will be grateful.

```
    private void showRoute(String route) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(route);
                String arrayData = jsonObject.getString("JsonData");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(arrayData);
                Log.d(TAG, "JSONArray" + ">>>>>>>>>>" + jsonArray);

                for (int i = 467; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    int month=5;//set search condition, i want to show a list , it's month > 5
//here is my search condition
                    if (Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("STARTMONTH"))>=month) {
                        String EDUTITLE = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("EDUTITLE");
                        String STARTMONTH = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("STARTMONTH");
                        String STARTDAY = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("STARTDAY");
                        String STARTDATE = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("STARTDATE");
                        String SPONSER = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("SPONSER");
                        String EDUSCORE = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("EDUSCORE");
                        String EDUIN = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("EDUIN");
                        String HOLDER = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("HOLDER");
                        ActivityListItem listItem = new ActivityListItem(EDUTITLE, STARTMONTH, STARTDAY, STARTDATE, SPONSER, EDUSCORE, EDUIN, HOLDER);
                        arrayList.add(listItem);
                    }else {
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        textForEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    //arrayListOrigin.add(listItem);
                }
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

and another question , if my data is 467~500  , my list will show 467~500 from up to down , what if i want to let it shows 500~467 from up to down , what should i do is more correct ?

I try some code like:   it show empty

```
String month="5";
if (month.equals(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("STARTMONTH"))) {
other code...
}
```

but if i try to compare EDUIN like this:  it works...

```
String eduin="0";
                if (eduin.equals(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("EDUIN"))) {
other code...
}
```

i don't get it now :(

Comment: can you add sample json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your if condition may not be executed because of this line
`String arrayData = jsonObject.getString("JsonData");`
In your response "JsonData" is a `JSONArray` not a `String` .
Try this instead.

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(route);
 JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("JsonData") ;
  for (int i = 467; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    //rest of your code
    }
```

Now if you want to item from 500 to 467 reverse the loop

```
for(int i = jsonArray.length()-1; i >= 467; i--){
if(Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("STARTMONTH"))>=month){
   // rest of the code..
}}
```

outside the loop hide recycleview like this

```
   if (arrayList.size() == 0) {
    //hide recycleview
       recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       textForEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

**Or**

Much more easier way

```
ArrayList<Element> tempElements = new ArrayList<Element>(arrayList);
Collections.reverse(tempElements);
```

Comment: thanks @sunil sunny i though your point is correct , but when i delete the search condition and try for(int i = jsonArray.length(); i >= 467; i--){
   // rest of the code..
   }   first  ,  it shows empty ,i don't get it....

Comment: thanks .  jsonArray.length()-1 is working , i got it now. it teach me a lots ,  but it's not working when i set month>=5 in my first question yet :(

Comment: That's because you are hiding recycleview... remove these lines and see

else {
           recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          textForEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }

Comment: if there is no data , it will go to hide recyclerView , but it must have data , if i set the search condition is month>5 right ?

Comment: Ok i got it now . I'm so stupid...I miss the point lost in my mind....
thanks @sunil sunny , you help me a lots , love you :)